# ASP.NET Web API / HMAC Authentication, how to authorize on user's behalf?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, hmacsha1

I'm reading this article http://rc3.org/2011/12/02/using-hmac-to-authenticate-web-service-requests/ and I understand how HMAC works I think.

The issue is that HMAC seems to authenticate the third party (relay party) only.  What if the third party wants to pass a user of my system and his/her  password to extract the user's specific data? I don't want to use OAuth 1.0 nor 2.0 because various issues with them. It seems to me, I need to authenticate the user too, not just authorize?

For instance, Evernote mobile app, it asks me for username/password and I'm sure it's calling some sort of Web API in the background.  It's not using OAuth 2.0 right? Because I don't see myself redirect to the provider site to "authorize". In this case, how did my username/password got passed to the back end service?

[Edit]

After thinking about it a bit, I'm assuming SSL is the solution? Once you have SSL, you can pass username/password to my web api in plain text and then I do whatever to authenticate the third party PLUS authenticate the user and respond with user's data?

In that case, the downside is I have to trust the third party? So they don't store my user's username+password, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, just because you don't see redirects, it does not mean OAuth is not used. I'm not saying Evernote uses OAuth. I do not know their architecture but Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant which is part of OAuth 2.0 is suitable for first-party applications and it  does no redirects.

Secondly, if you want to ensure your users do not share their credentials with the third-party app that consumes your web API, OAuth 2.0 is a great option and not sure why you do not want to use OAuth. You can also try WS-Federation with the help of WIF, though it is SOAP-ish. The last option will be coming up with your own redirects based mechanism by which your users submitting their credentials in a web page of yours is ensured but this is highly risky and not recommended. Why to reinvent the wheel? Other than these, you must only trust the third party.

Comment: @Bardri. Thanks. I just tried to read OAuth2.0 again, could you clarify how OAuth2.0 can obtain resource owner's credentials without going to the provider's site? A bit confused. 

In addition, I'm concerned with OAuth because I read these two articles http://homakov.blogspot.com/2013/03/oauth1-oauth2-oauth.html (who happened to hack facebook oAuth2.0 awhile ago) and http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/ (who happens to be the creator of OAuth)

Comment: Just saw Twitter's XAuth implementation which skips request token and authorization. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth and directly access AccessToken. Though, i have to highly trust the third party app... Like Twitter, third party needs to specifically request for such permission, so it's not like it's OAuth solved the problem per say...plus all the other factors mentioned in the above two links

Comment: and just FYI. I'm not saying OAuth2.0 is bad, but I don't trust the implementations out there. I mean facebook implementation (backed by their expert engineers, are still constantly having problems, I'm not sure there IS an implementation out there I can use)